Parallel connections to Salesforce
I am replicating data from a Salesforce environment using Informatica. The taskflow that executes this consists of 20+ data tasks running in parallel. I notice that no more than 2 run at any given time and have been looking for a reason why. I found a setting inside of Informatica data integration that sets the maximum number of parallel tasks and have it set to 15 but this didn't change performance.
Is the limit on the number of parallel jobs a setting in Salesforce, and is there any way to change it?
